# how to efficiently retrieve data from firebase/Firestore subcollection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm using firestore to store posts each post could have simple properties such as {title: 'hi', comment: true} I'm able to easily fetch the user's specific posts since my collection structure looks like this: posts/user.id/post/post.name so an example will be posts/1234sofa/post/cool day
with this way of structuring, I'm able to easily fetch data for the user, but I'm having trouble with two things how do I fetch and display all posts for my main feed, and what's the most effective way of doing this? here is my current function for fetching user-specific data:

```
   const submitpost = async () => {
    try {

const collectionRef=collection(db,`posts`,user.uid.toString(),'post')



      await addDoc(collectionRef, {
        post: post,
        timestamp: serverTimestamp(),
        canComment: switchValue,
        user: user.uid,
        avatar: user.photoURL,
        username: user.displayName,
      });
      toast({ title: "posted", status: "success", duration: 2000 });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

this specific function creates a structure like this in firebase posts are just takes and take is singular post respectively I just changed the name so its easier to understand:
[image]

now here is how im fetching the data for my spefic user:

```
       const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
      const [takes, settakes] = useState([]);
    const getData = async () => {
    // if user is present run function

    if (user) {
      // const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
      // const collectionRef = collection(docRef, "takes");
      // const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
      try {
        const docRef = doc(db, "posts", user.uid);
        const collectionRef = collection(db,'posts',user.uid,'takes');
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);

        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => ({
          id: d.id,
          ...d.data(),
        }));

        settakes(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      //
    }
  };
```

here is the function that doesn't work when fetching all data for main feed:

```
    const [user]=useAuthState(auth)
  const [allfeed, setallfeed] = useState([])
    const getData = async () => {
    if(user){
      const collectionRef = collection(db, "posts");
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
    const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => ({
      id: d.id,
      ...d.data(),
    }));
  // get data from firebase 
  setallfeed(data)
    }
    
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
    console.log('ran');
    console.log(allfeed);

    // rerun when user is present
  }, [user]);
```

when I console log the allfeed it returns an empty array so my main problem is how to do I get all the data from the posts collection meaning posts/userid/post/post.title I need to get these for every user. and secondly is there a more efficient way to structure my data?

Comment: Have you already tried using [`onSnaphot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) method?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `onSnapshot()` method if you want realtime updates from a collection or a specific document.

`setState()` does not make changes directly to the state object. It just creates queues for React core to update the state object of a React component.  If you add the state to the useEffect, it compares the two objects, and since they have a different reference, it once again fetches the items and sets the new items object to the state. The state updates then triggers a re-render in the component. And on, and on, and on...

If you just want to log your data into your console then you must use a temporary variable rather than using setState:

```
const getData = async () => {
    if(user){
        // Using `getDocs`
        const collectionRef = collection(db, "posts");
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => ({
            id: d.id,
            ...d.data(),
        }));

        console.log(data)

        // ============================================= //

        // Using `onSnapshot()`
        const q = query(collection(db, "posts"));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(d => ({
                id: d.id,
                ...d.data()
            }))

            console.log(data)
        });
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getData();
}, []);
```

You could also use multiple `useEffect()` to get the updated state of the object:

```
const getData = async () => {
    if(user){
        // Using `getDocs`
        const collectionRef = collection(db, "posts");
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => ({
            id: d.id,
            ...d.data(),
        }));

        setallfeed(data)

        // ============================================= //

        // Using `onSnapshot()`
        const q = query(collection(db, "posts"));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(d => ({
                id: d.id,
                ...d.data()
            }))

            setallfeed(data)
        });
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getData();
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(allfeed);
}, [allfeed]);
```

If you want to render it to the component then you should call the state in the component and map the data into it. Take a look at the sample code below:

```
const getData = async () => {
    if(user){
        // Using `getDocs`
        const collectionRef = collection(db, "posts");
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
        const data = querySnapshot.docs.map((d) => ({
            id: d.id,
            ...d.data(),
        }));

        setallfeed(data)

        // ============================================= //

        // Using `onSnapshot()`
        const q = query(collection(db, "posts"));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
            const data = querySnapshot.docs.map(d => ({
                id: d.id,
                ...d.data()
            }))

            setallfeed(data)
        });
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, []);
  
return (
    <div>
        <p>SomeData: <p/>
        {items.map((item) => (
        <p key={item.id}>{item.fieldname}</p>
        ))}
    </div>
);
```

---

For more information you may checkout these documentations:

- [Get data with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)
- [Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)